# Arduino CAN-BUSシールドは、Spresenseで使用可能ですか

Tags: spresense

CANバスを追加してNuttxから使用することを検討しています。[Arduino CAN BUSシールド](https://www.switch-science.com/catalog/3435/)というのを見つけたのですが、ちょうど[NuttxがドライバをもっているMCP2515](https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense-nuttx/tree/master/drivers/can)を備えているようですので使えるのではと期待しています。
上記シールドとSpresenseを併用した実績のあるかたがいれば対応可否や懸案等教えてください。
また他に対応するシールドや追加方法あればご教授ください。

Answer (score 0):

こんにちは。
ちょうど、CANを探していたので、ありがたい情報です。

私もこのデバイスを購入して試してみようと思いますが、
少なくとも、Spresenseでは、Shield側のICSPヘッダが干渉するため、
ICSPヘッダを取り除く加工が必要になりそうです。

その場合に、SPIの端子のアサインは、
貼り付けられているURLに記載されているように、
ジャンパで切り替えておかなくてはならないかもしれません。

> MISO、MOSI、SCKジャンパを切り替えることによって、一部の互換機用にSPIピンをICSPピンからD11～D13ピンに変更することができます（デフォルトはICSP）。

回答になってませんが、試してみたら、また共有します。

Answer (score 0):

Spresense のCANボードが販売されているようです。
こちらを使うと楽に接続できそうです。

https://nextstep.official.ec/items/38434337

ご参考まで。